# creating multiple sharedobject dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shared-objects

I would like to dynamically create multiple sharedobject to create multi-login and I used the below code for that. But it throws error.Please post if there is any way to do it.

```
var k:Number=0;
var signup:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("newSignUp");

signup_mc.signup_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, signupcheck);

function signupcheck(event:MouseEvent):void {
newusername = signup_mc.username_txt.text;
    newpassword = signup_mc.password_txt.text;
    signup.data.nwusername+k = newusername;
    signup.data.nwpassword+k = newpassword; 
    signup.flush();
k++;
}
```

Comment: put the error message to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there would be errors. Assigning a+b=c will be wrong in most languages, I guess. If you want keys like nwusername0, nwusername1 etc you need to create keys in a correct way:

```
signup.data["nwusername" + k] = newusername;
signup.data["nwpassword" + k] = newpassword;
```